# Recover Deleted Data Table Azure Mob Service

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I accidentally deleted a table from Data of Mobile Service. Is there any way I can recover it?

I used the default free database given with making a mobile service. I really do not care about the data in table, instead I really want the scripts than ran on it.

.........................................
In order to retrieve the data I did the following:
Cloned the mobile service, reverted it to a previous commit, copied the deleted table and its script files, pulled again from the server, added the table and the script files where they should be, added the files to git tracking index, pushed the commit to master

Now the files are there in the azure mobile service, but the table is not being displayed in the GUI.
I tried to restart the azure mobile service but still it is not there.

In order to confirm the table and its files were indeed there I even cloned the mob service again and this time in the table folder I had users.json and its script files, but sadly they are not  visible in azure portal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the table to show again in the UI, you need to use the portal create table command. It will basically noop if it detects the table already exists in SQL. I don't believe it will touch your table scripts, however it may override the .json permissions file.

If it does override the js files, then after creating the table through the UI you can revert the commit that changed the json/js table files as part of that process.

At that point you should be good again.

Comment: I did get my scripts back, although the table was overwritten.. but that's not a bit deal :)